# Sending email as attachment in java

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have an image in my d drive and i want to send it as an email attachment in **java**. Recipients mail will be entered by sender, I just want to attach it to my email account. Please help.
thank you.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaand this has literally nothing to do with **javascript**, you should start by removing that tag.

Comment: Please more details and what do you means by " I just want to attach it to my email account"

Comment: This site does not provide a code writing service, which appears to be what you're asking for. How this got an upvote is beyond me.

Comment: Nothing to do with javascript you can go with this link http://www.journaldev.com/2532/java-program-to-send-email-using-smtp-gmail-tls-ssl-attachment-image-example

Comment: SO is done to help you when you recieve and error, and not to do somebodies else work

Comment: i am able to do it in java but i am not able to do it in javascript. some hints can help me out!

Comment: @KevinEsche i think doing somebody else's work and helping them out are 2 different things and you are confused.

Comment: @esprittn i have an image in my computer and i have to attach it to my email id to send it. But i dont know where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link(my answer to that question) for email sending utility code. You've got to add few line of code to send mail with attachment.

[On submit the information should come to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31022913/on-submit-the-information-should-come-to-email/31023735#31023735)

In EmailUtility.java after

```
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
```

comment

```
msg.setText(message);
```

And add the following code:

```
     // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");
    String attachFile = "C:/imgname.jpg";
    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    // adds attachments

    if(reason.equals("attach"))
    if (attachFile != null) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachPart.attachFile(attachFile);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
    }

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart);
```

You've got to change C:/imgname.jpg to your file name along with its path.